# How to relink libtool-built executables with correct Library Path without install?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, autotools, libtool, ldd

A have a project build with GNU autotools. Now I have a tiny change and only want to copy *one single library* `libmylib.so` and *one program* `myprog.x` (using that library) from the whole collection.

I do not want to use `make install` because I have to be very careful not to overwrite all the other stuff.

When I do

```
ldd .libs/myprog.x
```

I see that the library used is -- as expected -- the freshly built library and not that one in `/usr/lib/`.

```
$ ldd .libs/myprog.x
libmylib.so.0 => /home/user/project/.libs/libmylib.so.0 (0x003bb000)
libnsl.so.1 => /lib/libnsl.so.1 (0x00f57000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/tls/libc.so.6 (0x00948000)
libz.so.1 => /usr/lib/libz.so.1 (0x0024e000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 => /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x00ee7000)
```

How can I tell `make` or `libtool` to **relink** `myprog.x` so that I can copy it manually to `/usr/bin/`? After copying `libmylib.so` to `/usr/lib/` of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I worked this out by running `make -n install | less`.)

You probably want to install the libraries and program (if it's linked using libtool) with libtool, so try something like:

```
sudo ./libtool --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c libmylib.la /usr/lib
sudo ./libtool --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c myprog.x /usr/bin
```

Libtool might ask you to run a `./libtool --mode=finish` command as well. I'd trust its advice. Before doing any of this, I'd run the commands with the `--dry-run` option and without `sudo` to see what exactly is going to happen.

Note that I'm not running the system `libtool`, but the one that was created by the `configure` script.

Comment: `sudo`, eh? One of my challenges was that `--prefix=$HOME`. If it were not I could have just called `make install` without `sudo` to get everything except the install-copy. But: I did not know about `make -n` and also did not guess `libtool --dry-run`. That was *the* hint. Am I right in guessing that using the created `libtool` *may* make a difference, but should not?

Comment: I don't know what effect using the system `libtool` vs the generated `libtool` will have.